# Where is GIS categorized?

Tags: terminology

I am always in doubt as to where to categorize GIS. For instance, when you use a search engine to look for a job, you are asked to choose the category your job falls in. Or when you search for a book on an online library:

[image]

The above list contains the common major fields you are asked to choose from.

What's the most relevant field to categorize GIS?

Comment: Given that list, a GIS job could fall into **any** of those categories (except probably Music), which makes this question *opinion-based*.

Comment: Would be under IT & Software in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the list and there aren't any other categories, I'd have no doubt and put it in IT & Software. I think you cannot confuse what GIS is and what do you use it for.